# How to count number of bytes sent/received by "net/http" Client?

Tags: go

Is it possible to get total number of bytes sent and received during `"net/http"` `Client.Do` request (for monitoring or statistical purposes)?

If not possible, how could you get this information with least development effort and performance impact?

Comment: Do you care about the body size or the entire transmission ? ie http headers, tcp headers etc

Comment: I'd like to have whole http request and response (headers + body) sizes

Answer (score 1):

For the number of bytes sent, you should be able to just dump the request before sending if you're using client.Do:

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequestOut

```
dump, err := httputil.DumpRequestOut(req, true)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

fmt.Printf("request len:%d\n\n%q",len(dump), dump)
```

For the number of bytes received, do you mean the no of bytes in the response? If so use httputil.DumpResponse:

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpResponse

```
dump, err := httputil.DumpResponse(resp, true)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("response len:%d\n\n%q", len(dump),dump)
```

That will get you the counts, in terms of least impact, the last impact would be to measure body and headers separately by looping through headers, as then you won't be dumping to a string, but it's unlikely to make a huge difference to you so I'd try the simple way first. See the code for the two functions above by viewing src on golang.org docs, you could just pull that out and replace accumulating bytes with counting them.

For tracing execution, have a look at the httptrace package and client trace:

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptrace/

if you want to debug connections this is a useful tool.

Comment: I checked, but was unable to see how can I receive connection stats, i.e. count bytes sent and received. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I've added some more detail, looks like you can't get stats from httptrace, but it still might be useful for you. I think you want httputil which has methods to dump, and you can just count bytes in the dumped headers + body.

Comment: @vearutop if the answer does what you wanted, please accept it.

Comment: Though it does work, this solution does not qualify for minimal performance impact. I made a small benchmark to check: https://gist.github.com/vearutop/954958701df46162467565fca943a840. And I see that dumping data is almost TWICE as slow comparing to not dumping.
Some counting wrapper would be much more efficient.

Comment: Perhaps consider the suggestion in the post to use the source from those methods, shld be simple enough. Normally this kind of counting I would only turn on during debug, it will obviously have some impact so if performance is a concern, don't do it in production.